# How is it possible to have a add-on run immediately after you open blender?

Tags: add-on

What I am needing to do is that when I open blender it toggles the add-on. The add-on that I am using is the Virtual Reality ViewPoint. What I want is for that addon to activate right when I open Blender.How is this possible?

Comment: Somewhat related http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/1689/15543

Comment: Which one? Please provide a link to the addon.

Comment: https://github.com/dfelinto/virtual_reality_viewport

Comment: Sounds more like a bug. Make sure you saved your user prefs. Otherwise might be better reporting this behavior as issue on github.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tested this with the addon you mention but two things that may help.

1. Enable the addon, adjust the options and [Save User Settings](https://www.blender.org/manual/preferences/introduction.html#save-the-new-preferences). This will keep the addon enabled every time you start blender.
2. Setup the viewport, then [*File->Save Startup File*](https://www.blender.org/manual/preferences/introduction.html#startup-file). The startup file defines the scene contents and screen layouts when blender is started. This might allow the addons viewport settings to be set the way you want when starting blender.

If the startup file doesn't keep the addons viewport settings then you could use a python script to set the options the way you want and save it into the startup file so it can be [run on startup](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/36822/935).

Answer (score 2):

If you launch blender from the command line, you can designate a startup .py file which could either be the addon itself or trigger the loading of the addon.

Sample cli command:

```
blender --background --python startup_script.py
```

Depending on your OS, there are different ways to make the command line call clickable as an executable app for convenience.