# How to make permanent custom tab and removing some submenu in tab tools (T)?

Tags: scripting

I create new tab by using phyton template in blender, but I don't know How to make it permanent. and I want removing some submenu in tab.
I want to remove this, do you know how?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are referring to as a submenu is the header of a panel. The template that you created includes a class that inherits from a Panel, the `bl_category` value in the panel class decides what tab the panel will be shown in.

Tabs only exist if there is a panel to be shown in them. When there are no panels to show the tab is removed. To make a tab permanent you need to have a panel to show in it that is always available, this may be a python script set to [auto-run on startup](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/36822/935) that is saved to your startup.blend or an addon that is set to be enabled on startup, you do that by enabling the addon and then [saving user settings](https://www.blender.org/manual/preferences/introduction.html#save-the-new-preferences).