# Adding specific information to file output

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, add-on

Is there a way to add extra information to the filename that is created by `Blender`? For example, if  I'm rendering images of an animation, is there a way to have `Blender` automatically add something like sample size to the file name it creates? Something like **%samp**?

I'm trying to end up with something like

**C:\Blender\rendered\images\my_animation_00001-2000.jpg**

Where 2000 is the sample size that was used for that particular image.

Comment: Not directly through the UI, as far as I know, but it may be possible with scripting through the Python API

Comment: Blender only adds the frame number to the filename. I expect you can do what you want by setting up a [handler](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.app.handlers.html) that sets the render filepath.

Answer (score 2):

You can add an [application handler](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.app.handlers.html) to be run before rendering that sets the output filename with the desired information. You can use [python's string format](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) to fill in the filename from a template string.

```
import bpy

def set_filepath(scn):
    scn.render.filepath = '//renders/animation_{0:04}-{1}.jpg'.format(
            scn.frame_current, scn.cycles.samples)

bpy.app.handlers.render_pre.append(set_filepath)
```

By pasting this into a [text block in blender](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/text_editor.html) and adjusting the filename for the file, it can then be [setup to run when the blend file is opened](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/36822/935) so that it will always be available when using the file.

Note that the handler will set the filename, that means you adjust the filename in the script - not in the render settings.