# Can I permanently add add a method to the driver namespace?

Tags: python, scripting, customization, drivers

I have a method `x` which I can add to the driver namespace like this:

```
bpy.app.driver_namespace["x"] = x
```

but the namespace is reset everytime I restart Blender, which then messes up my drivers. Is there a way to permanently add it to the namespace or auto-execute this script when starting Blender?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Put this code into a Python file and place it into `~/.config/blender/2.78/scrips/startup/my_driver_stuff.py` (replace ~/config/blender with `%APPDATA%/Blender Foundation/Blender` on Windows, and something along those lines on MacOS).

```
import bpy

@bpy.app.handlers.persistent
def setup_driver(*args):
    bpy.app.driver_namespace["x"] = x
bpy.app.handlers.load_post.append(setup_driver)
setup_driver()
```

Comment: ok now that's weird... It created a "__pycache__" folder in the startup folder, presumably containing the compiled script. But the method is still not in the namespace...

Comment: I've updated my answer to use a load_post handler. Haven't tried it myself, but it should work like this ;-)