# Update Blend File with Many Python Scripts by Command Line

Tags: python, rendering, scripting, workflow

[This linked post does not answer the question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36821/start-script-on-open-blender-file). That post is for a **single** script, and to do this, you still need the GUI. I have **no GUI access** and **1000 unique script files**. I do not think this will work. The only work around I have found is to not use render farms and instead use a computing cluster like aws where you can use the command line below to render.

---

I have 1000 script files that set various parameters of my Blend scene.
Previously, I have been rendering with the command line like this:

```
Blender -b myFile.blend -P myScript0001.txt -f 1
Blender -b myFile.blend -P myScript0002.txt -f 2
Blender -b myFile.blend -P myScript0003.txt -f 3
```

In order to render this on a render farm, I cannot use the script files, they must be included in the Blend file. Is there a way to update the blend file to include the script file by the command line? I do not have the option to use the GUI to do this.
Or maybe I reference a json file in my script that I host publicly on my website? Is something like this possible, for example:

```
#myScript0001.txt
import bpy
bpy.data.objects["Empty"].location[0] = {link-to-json-file}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Read the files write to text, save blend.**

Here is an example script.

- Globs all text files in folder (hardcoded, could pass as argument)
- Create a textblock with same stem name
- Read the contents into textblock
- Save blend to keep changes.

Script, edit directory path to suit.

```
import bpy
from pathlib import Path

# glob all txt files from
dir_path = "/home/batfinger/foo"
txt_dir = Path(dir_path)

# glob for txt files. 
glob = "*.txt"


for f in txt_dir.glob(glob):
    text = bpy.data.texts.new(f.stem)
    text.write(f.read_text())

# save
#bpy.ops.wm.save_mainfile()
```

Comment: This works, thank you! Simple solution